# Can I pass arguments to an external (CLR) SQL Server trigger?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers, sqlclr

I have a trigger in SQL Server, but I need to pass arguments to the CLR code, i.e., information not provided in the trigger context.

Is something like this even possible?

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger ON MyTable FOR INSERT
AS EXTERNAL NAME MyAssembly.MyNamespace.MyTriggerHandler("Foo", "Bar")
```

These arguments would be static, of course.

The number of argument permutations is discrete, but creating a separate class or function in the CLR assembly for each would be unwieldy, and would require a compile / deploy step I want to avoid every time another trigger is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little research, it appears what I want to do, can't be done.

Methods passed using the trigger "external name" clause must be parameterless, and the SqlTriggerContext cannot be modified in the CREATE TRIGGER statement.

I ended up going the permutation route and just having fewer variations of supported arguments. Perhaps .NET integration will be a little more robust next time around.

Comment: You can't pass parameters to normal triggers either. Why would you want parameters on SQLCLR triggers? The INSERTED, DELETED tables are available for querying inside a SQLCLR trigger just as they are inside a normal trigger

Answer (score 1):

In a sense you can pass information to a Trigger (whether T-SQL or SQLCLR), just not directly as you are showing in the question. Still, you have 2 or 3 options for passing information that is not part of the DML operation itself to any Triggers in chain of events:

1. Local temporary table
2. [SET CONTEXT_INFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187768.aspx) / [CONTEXT_INFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180125.aspx)
3. On SQL Server 2016 or newer: [sp_set_session_context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt605113.aspx) / [SESSION_CONTEXT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt590806.aspx)

In all cases you would get the values by executing a `SqlCommand` (use `"Context Connection = true;"` as the connection string) with an output `SqlParameter` to pull the value into the .NET code.

Answer (score 0):

yeah you can use the sp_OA procedures for this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238863(SQL.80).aspx

Comment: This is for creating OLE objects, it has nothing to do with CLR-based external trigger code.